# ANDROID: Chane Image state uniquely onClick

Tags: android, uiimageview, click, android-imageview, facebook-like

Is there any method to change image/image state onClick uniquely. eg: Make a general method that only changes the pressed image and all the rest images stays normal.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:src="@drawable/like"></ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"

                android:src="@drawable/like"></ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it programmatically

kotlin

```
val img1 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img1)
img1.setOnClickListener{
    img1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.your_image));
}

val img2 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img2)
img2.setOnClickListener{
    img2.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.your_image));
}
```

Java

```
img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1)
img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2)
img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image)
    }
});    
img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image)
    }
});
```

**Note:** minor tweaks maybe needed